# Modifying `iter` chain to use `and_then`, etc

Tags: rust

I have a function that looks like:

```
type Attributes = HashMap<String, json::Json>;
type Store = Arc<RwLock<HashMap<String, RwLock<Attributes>>>>;

fn get(store: &Store, key: &str) -> Option<Attributes> {
    store.read().iter()
        .filter_map(|g| (*g).get(key) )
        .filter_map(|v| v.read().ok() )
        .map(|v| (*v).clone() )
        .next()
}
```

This compiles and works just fine. However, for my own edification, I have been trying to modify this to use standard `Result`/`Option` methods (without converting the `LockResult` to an `Iter`), something like:

```
store.read().ok()
    .and_then(|g| (*g).get(key) )
    .and_then(|v| v.read().ok() )
    .map(|v| (*v).clone() );
```

But this tells me that `g does not live long enough`. I've tried adding `ref` and `as_ref` at various places, but can't get it to compile. What am I missing?

I know I can get it to work like:

```
    store.read().ok()
        .and_then(|g| {
            (*g).get(key)
                .and_then(|v| v.read().ok() )
                .map(|v| (*v).clone() )
        })
```

But I would like to be able to chain it like in the `iter` case.

Comment: (Potentially noob question) Isn't this the difference between `iter()` and `into_iter()`? You might want to use `into_iter()` to move ownership to the rest of your chain so that your references live throughout?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, thanks for the comment! Yes, I think this is exactly the difference between `iter` and `into_iter`--but in reverse. I **do** want to use `iter` rather than `into_iter`, and in fact I want an `and_then` variant that does something like `iter`, but I can't figure out the right combo of `as_ref`, etc., that does this. When I change the first example above to use `into_iter`, I get the same error messages as my second example.

Comment: I don't suppose you could put together a MVCE on the playpen for me/others to tinker with?

Comment: Sure, here is a simplified example: http://is.gd/ogNom8.

Answer (score 3):

OK, the compiler is really messing with me tonight.

I got this incantation to compile:

```
fn get(store: &Store, key: &str) -> Option<Attributes> {
    let r = store.read();
    let x = r.as_ref().ok()
        .and_then(|g| (*g).get(key) )
        .and_then(|v| v.read().ok() )
        .map(|v| (*v).clone() );
    x
}
```

If you inline either `r` or `x`, you'll get another `does not live long enough` error again. I'm not sure why, since in principle, the lock guard should remain active as a temporary until the end of the statement.